# Need help on how to convert this select to a DELETE statement:

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I need help as to how to convert this select to a delete statement.

```
SELECT stud_term_sum_div.id_num,   
     stud_term_sum_div.hrs_enrolled,   
     stud_term_sum_div.transaction_sts,   
     student_crs_hist.crs_cde,   
     student_crs_hist.transaction_sts  
  FROM stud_term_sum_div,   
     student_crs_hist  
 WHERE ( stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde = student_crs_hist.yr_cde ) and  
     ( stud_term_sum_div.trm_cde = student_crs_hist.trm_cde ) and  
     ( stud_term_sum_div.id_num = student_crs_hist.id_num ) and  
     ( ( stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde = '2013' ) AND  
     ( stud_term_sum_div.trm_cde = 'FA' ) AND  
     ( stud_term_sum_div.hrs_enrolled >= 3.00 ) AND  
     ( student_crs_hist.transaction_sts = 'D' ) )
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward conversion is below:

```
DELETE * FROM stud_term_sum_div
WHERE ( stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde = student_crs_hist.yr_cde ) and  
 ( stud_term_sum_div.trm_cde = student_crs_hist.trm_cde ) and  
 ( stud_term_sum_div.id_num = student_crs_hist.id_num ) and  
 ( ( stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde = '2013' ) AND  
 ( stud_term_sum_div.trm_cde = 'FA' ) AND  
 ( stud_term_sum_div.hrs_enrolled >= 3.00 ) AND  
 ( student_crs_hist.transaction_sts = 'D' ) )
```

BUT, before you go executing that, please check that the `WHERE` clause really contains the conditions to be used for deletion. Note that this SQL statement will delete the entire row (a/k/a record) when the attributes in the `WHERE` clause satisfy the stated conditions.

If you only want to remove the data from the attributes (as opposed to the entire record), you'd need to use an SQL `UPDATE` statement instead. The (simplified) syntax for that is as follows:

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET <attribute1> = <value1>
[, SET <attribute_n> = <value_n>...]
WHERE <conditions on which the record should be updated>
```

Doing a search on Bing, google, <insert your favorite search engine here> for "SQL DELETE" or "SQL UPDATE" should get you all the information you need (e.g. MSDN, for one).